# Change USER on CircleCI

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

This is killing me, cannot find an answer...I just want to change the current user from root to the pre-created user called "node" given a "node:9" base image.

Here is the .circleci/config.yml file that I have now:

```
# Javascript Node CircleCI 2.0 configuration file
#
# Check https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/ for more details
#
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:9

      # Specify service dependencies here if necessary
      # CircleCI maintains a library of pre-built images
      # documented at https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/
      # - image: circleci/mongo:3.4.4

    working_directory: ~/repo

    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:  # Download and cache dependencies
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: sudo npm install --loglevel=warn

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: echo "here are the tests"
```

Here is how you do it with Docker:

```
RUN echo "newuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
USER newuser
```

but I believe that the node:9 images come with a pre-created user, so that could be simply:

```
 USER node
 WORKDIR /home/node/app
```

**but I can't find any docs on how to change from the root user to a non-root user for CircleCI.**

Here are some docs:
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can choose which available user to run within the docker image using the `user` argument to the `image` section.

```
docker:
  - image: circleci/node:9
    user: node
```